# We're sorry but project doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue

Tags: docker, vue.js, nginx, docker-compose, deployment

I have a vueJs project that I want to run using docker.
Here is the content of my Dockerfile:

```
# build stage
FROM node:10-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./growth-tracker-web-client/package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./growth-tracker-web-client .
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=builder /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And build without any errors.
But when I open the project in browser
I see a white page
And I checked the Inspect element network tab, I found this message:
`We're sorry but project doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.`

I try different versions of docker image like: FROM node:{version}-alpine

I got an error in some of them
And some others have the same problem.

Note that it is working on another server about 6 months ago with this docker image:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as builder
```

But in the installation section of the new server in npm install part, received the following error:

```
Step 5/11 : RUN npm install --force
 ---> Running in b4c57ca3280b
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm notice 
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 9.6.7 -> 9.8.1
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.8.1>
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@9.8.1` to update!
npm notice 
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /app/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.17.1 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "/usr/bin/python2.7", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (/app/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:484:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:406:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at F (/app/node_modules/which/which.js:68:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at E (/app/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /app/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /app/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /app/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:210:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 3.10.0-1160.95.1.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/app/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /app/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.17.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-08-20T06_46_13_811Z-debug-0.log
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c npm install --force' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

and also javascript is enable on my browser

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding python2 to Docker using node:16.15.1 (alpine 3.16)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73619662/adding-python2-to-docker-using-node16-15-1-alpine-3-16)

Comment: That sounds like javascript is disabled in your browser. Shouldn't be a server fault.